# Send SMS just once for GPS location

Tags: android, gps, coordinates

I'm making an application which runs in background in a mobile. When I send a sms with HDPK GPS, the application is supposed to send the GPS co-ordinates of the cell on a fixed number. I receive the GPS co-ordinates on the number but continuously. I have tried everything with removeupdates but all in vain! Please help me sort this issue out. Also when the application listens in the background for the SMS,the GPS and the application too crashes when receives the message, although I get just the toast before the crash. But if the application is running on the screen, it wont crash and continuously sends messages of the co-ordinates.

```
public class RecActivity extends Activity {
double current_lat, current_lng;
boolean flag=true;
// String provider=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
BroadcastReceiver SMSbr = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {

Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {

Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
if (messages.length > -1) {
String messagebody=messages[0].getMessageBody();
if(messagebody.toString().matches("HDPK GPS"))
{

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(RecActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();                   

Toast.makeText(RecActivity.this,"GPS STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,1, mlocListener);                                 

}

                                                                                           }

}
}

};

IntentFilter SMSfilter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
this.registerReceiver(SMSbr, SMSfilter);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
Toast.makeText(RecActivity.this,"GPS WORKING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
current_lat=loc.getLatitude();
current_lng=loc.getLongitude();
String Text = "My location is: " +

"Latitude = " + current_lat +

"Longitude = " + current_lng;

SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,Text , null, null);
Toast.makeText(RecActivity.this, "SMS SENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



}



public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,"GPS Disabled" , null, null);

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,"GPS Enabled" , null, null);

}

 public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}

}
```

The Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:name=".RecActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter android:priority="100">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

Here is my code:

```
package RecSM.Rec.receiveharsh;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RecActivity extends Activity {
double current_lat, current_lng;
boolean flag=true;
LocationManager mlocManager;
LocationListener mlocListener;
// String provider=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
BroadcastReceiver SMSbr = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {

Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {

Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
if (messages.length > -1) {


String messagebody=messages[0].getMessageBody();


if(messagebody.toString().matches("HDPK GPS"))
{

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(RecActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();                   

Toast.makeText(RecActivity.this,"GPS STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,1, mlocListener);                                 

}


}

}
}

};

IntentFilter SMSfilter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
this.registerReceiver(SMSbr, SMSfilter);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {


Toast.makeText(RecActivity.this,"GPS WORKING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
.show();

current_lat=loc.getLatitude();
current_lng=loc.getLongitude();
String Text = "My location is: " +

"Latitude = " + current_lat +

"Longitude = " + current_lng;

SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,Text , null, null);
Toast.makeText(RecActivity.this, "SMS SENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);


}



public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,"GPS Disabled" , null, null);

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,"GPS Enabled" , null, null);

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String Text = "My location is: " +

"Latitude = " + current_lat +

"Longitude = " + current_lng;

SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,Text , null, null);
Toast.makeText(RecActivity.this, "SMS SENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener); <<<<<<<<<<<< include this
```

Code looks fine to me.

**Is you device have GPS hardware in it??.**

Why dont you try fetching location from network provider.
   Make sure you have android.permission.internet in manifest before trying this code.

```
if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .isConnected()
                || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected())
        {
            /*Log.d("vipul", "WIFI or GPRS Connected");*/
            if (locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
            {
                Constants.CONNECTED = true;
                /*Log.v("tripSketch", "NETWORK Provider Enabled");*/
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this);
            } else
            {
                Constants.CONNECTED = false;
                /*Log.d("vipul",
                        "Please enable Wireless networks in Location Setting!!");*/
                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Please enable Wireless networks in Location Setting!!",
                        10000).show();
            }

        } else if (locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            Constants.CONNECTED = true;
            /*Log.d("vipul", "GPS Provider Enabled!");*/
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 100, this);

        } else
        {
            /*Log.d("vipul", "Neither GPS NOR EDGE/GPRS CONNECTED");*/
            Constants.CONNECTED = false;
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "Please connect EDGE/GPRS \nAlso Enable Wireless networks in Location Setting!!",
                    10000).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: mlocaManager is not global. Hence I cannot call it there. If I make it global, the application crashes

Comment: I made the locationmanager and listener global and added the lines as per your suggestion.Now I'm testing the application directly on my cell. Once I install and send a sms to it, when it receives the message, nothing happens. Now if I open the app to see the interface, then send the message, the GPS gets activated and I get the toast. But shortly the application crashes.Any idea?

Comment: Yes I do have GPS hardware. I'm running it on Sony Xperia Ray ST18i. And also as I told you my code sends me the GPS locations but it fails to stop. Keeps on sending. I don't know how to stop it from continously sending messages of the changed locations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Why but it works somehow )))

```
package net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging;

import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class SmsReceiver extends  BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener {

String strPhone;
String strMessage;
String strGPS;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
@Override

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    strPhone = "";
    strMessage = "";
    strGPS="";

    if (bundle != null) {
        // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            strPhone+=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            strMessage+=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

        }

        if (strMessage.contains(":)) ...")){

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
            List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);
            /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop*/
            Location l = null;

            final int updateTime = 2000; // ms
            final int updateDistance = 10; // meter
            final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            final String p = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(p, updateTime, updateDistance,
                    this);
            double[] gps = new double[2];

            for (int ii=providers.size()-1; ii>=0; ii--) {
                    l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(ii));
                    if (l != null) break;
            }

            if (l != null) {
                    gps[0] = l.getLatitude();
                    gps[1] = l.getLongitude();
                    Log.d("gps[0]", "gps[1]");
            }

      strGPS= String.valueOf(gps[0]) + " " + String.valueOf(gps[1]);
      sendSMS(strPhone, strGPS);
        }
        }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```